# GIT Bash MingW32 Rails Console - Text input fails after exit and restart console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, msysgit

I [installed Rails](http://railsinstaller.org/en) and I am having issues with the Rails console in Git Bash (MINGW32).

The first time I launch the Rails console using `rails c`, I can input text and everything works as expected.  However if I exit the rails console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> then start the Rails console again, the text input is wrong.

[image: Example]

In the example, I started the Rails console, input "Zombie.first", got the expected response, exited the console, started it again, entered "Zombie.first" again, but the console actually executes "Zoiefr".  Any text I enter after this will be similarly affected until restarting git bash.

I performed the RailsInstaller install on two different Windows machines with the same result.

Does anybody have suggestions for how to fix it, or for other Windows development environments to try?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use images to convey data, code, errors, or anything where we'd likely want to copy/paste information. Instead, copy, then paste, the information into the question, formatting it appropriately. Images can't be searched and if the link rots and breaks it makes the question difficult to understand, especially for those searching for similar solutions in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!